# How do I change the order of elements and control flow in responsive css

Tags: css, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm using skeleton and here is the responsive layout that I want:

mobile layout - Title, Image, Description all in one column stack

desktop layout - The title and description to the right of the image

[image: Mobile and Desktop Layouts]

How should I structure the html and css so that the responsive layout can change from one to the other using css and media queries only?  I tried floating the image to the left in the desktop layout and making the title a block element in the mobile layout:

```
<div class="container">
<span class="date">10/1/2012</span>
<span class="title">title</span>
<img class="thumbnail" src="http://www.placehold.it/300x200">
<p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut nisl urna, posuere et tincidunt id, malesuada id libero. Sed vel neque tellus. Nulla et justo eu sapien accumsan eleifend eget id enim. Suspendisse sagittis, erat in mattis sagittis, dolor leo molestie nisi, eget cursus massa est at erat.
</p>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Mobile CSS

```
.title {
     display:block;
}

​.thumbnail {
}

.conatainer {
 width:320px;
}
```

Desktop CSS

```
​.title {
     position:relative;
}

​.thumbnail {
    float:left;
}

.conatainer {
 width:960px;
}
```

This seems to work for the most part except the description wraps below the photo surrounding it on the bottom of the photo if the text is long enough, instead of just keeping to the right column.

How should I do this if I am using skeleton or one of the responive grid systems, should I be using their column classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `float: left` also on `.description` paragraph on `desktop.css` stylesheet. This will make expand your paragraph in its own "column".

Then, remember to also apply a clearing to `.container` element

Comment: thanks, doing that and setting a width to the descrption element did the trick.

Comment: if your container is 600px wide and your image is 300px wide just set a width of 300px or less to the paragraph

Comment: one other question, I realized that I need to have a date above the title in another line, and if I add that element above title with a line break it messes things up.  Can I do a block element wrapped in the inline .title element?  I would like the date to line up like title on the right side of the image in the desktop layout.

Comment: link to the html... http://jsfiddle.net/9e6tf/5/ I need the date to appear in a seperate line above title..

Comment: even imho is a bit unfair un-accept the question due to a change of the question I will take a look

Comment: Hey Fabrizio, I apologize about unaccepting the answer, I thought it was just a flag to indicate whether there was still a question or not, since digging into it I realized there was another twist to the requriements that I forgot to include.  My mis-understanding.  Will accept again for you.